# How can I change gridview templatecolumn order dynamically?

Tags: gridview, templates, dynamic

How can I change gridview templatecolumn order dynamically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. **Iterate** through all **columns** of the **GridView** object and **Store** them in a **collection**.

   ```
   List<DataControlField> columns = new List<DataControlField>();
   foreach (DataControlField column in gv.Columns)
   {
       columns.Add(column);
   }
   ```
2. **Rearrange** the **column-objects** as you want in the collection.

   ```
   //Rearrange columns' collection..
   ```
3. **Clear all columns** of the GridView object and **add columns from the collection** to **GridView** object.

   ```
    gv.Columns.Clear();
    foreach (DataControlField column in columns)
    {
        gv.Columns.Add(column);
    }
   ```

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/03/move--autogenerate-columns-at-leftmost-part-of-the-gridview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to work with template fields.
After removing and re-adding the columns the template fields are empty
(the bound fields show the correct values).

Answer (score 0):

On the `RowCreated` event, iterate through each column, save the first cell of each row (the template field) on a varible (`oCell`) and delete it from the collection, then use `column.Add(oCell)` to add it to the end of the collection.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){

    GridViewRow row = e.Row;
    // Intitialize TableCell list
    List<TableCell> columns = new List<TableCell>();
    foreach (DataControlField column in GridView1.Columns)
    {
        //Get the first Cell /Column
        TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];
        // Then Remove it after
        row.Cells.Remove(cell);
        //And Add it to the List Collections
        columns.Add(cell);
    }

    // Add cells
    row.Cells.AddRange(columns.ToArray());
}
```

http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/06/03/move--autogenerate-columns-at-leftmost-part-of-the-gridview.aspx