# how to move auto generated columns to left side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i  have gridview and i am adding rows at runtime using datatable as datasource.but i want to add delete command field to grid view.I add it and run it.But i got delete button at left position.I want to change that delete button to last of gridview.Means after autogenerated columns.Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This posting has what you need to know to put your generated columns in the leftmost part:

[Move AutoGenerate Columns at LeftMost Part of the GridView Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011574/how-can-i-change-gridview-templatecolumn-order-dynamically)

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the order by doing the following :-

```
YourDataColumn.SetOrdinal(0);
```

This allows you to move the column to to nay position.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){

        GridViewRow row = e.Row;
        // Intitialize TableCell list
        List<TableCell> columns = new List<TableCell>();
        foreach (DataControlField column in GridView1.Columns)
        {
            if (row.Cells.Count > 0)
            {
            //Get the first Cell /Column
            TableCell cell = row.Cells[0];
            // Then Remove it after
            row.Cells.Remove(cell);
            //And Add it to the List Collections
            columns.Add(cell);
            }
        }

        // Add cells
        row.Cells.AddRange(columns.ToArray());
}
```