# Change order of columns in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am using gridView. I have some auto generated columns and some generated by me.
Now the column which I have generated is displayed first and then the auto generated columns.
I want to display auto generated columns first and then my generated columns.

IMP Note :- I can't use this (for example): -

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="My First Column" DataField="myField1" />
```

because some of my Datafield columns are dynamic.

Comment: What you tried?  Post your code.

Comment: var columnToMove = myGridView.Columns[1];
myGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(1);
myGridView.Columns.Insert(0, columnToMove);

Comment: This is already covered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011574/how-can-i-change-gridview-templatecolumn-order-dynamically

Answer (score 0):

I think you add likes

```
 YourGridView.Columns.Add(yourNewColumn);
```

You can add grid column using index ,

```
 YourGridView.Columns.Insert(1, yourNewColumn);
```

In this code , the 1 makes it go into the second column (zero-based indexing ) !